# How to add custom room option in mod_muc_room.erl for opts table field (muc_room) in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I need to add new custom option in opts in muc_room table field in ejabberd db, but i also need to modify the mod_muc_room erl files and other related file. please help proper way to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Define the new option in include/mod_muc_room.hrl and add it in mod_muc_room.erl like all the other options. The best way is to copy code already written for another option.